# Can a Markov chain converge faster than a geometric rate?

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, markov-chains, mixing

In Theorem 4.9 of the book Markov Chains and Mixing Times by Levin & Peres, there is a convergence theorem for ergodic Markov chains which states that there exist constants $C > 0$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that
$$\sup_{x \in \mathcal{X}}\|P^t(x) - \pi\|_\text{TV} \leq C \alpha^t$$

Here $\mathcal{X}$ is the state space of the Markov chain, $P$ is a time independent transition kernel, and $\pi$ is its stationary distribution. A Markov chain that has this convergence rate is called geometric uniform ergodic.

Is this the fastest rate at which a Markov chain can converge? If true, is there a way to prove it? If false, are there examples of chains that converge at a rate faster than geometric?

Edit: I realize that i.i.d. chains have "already" converged, so they're obviously faster than an ergodic MC. However, I'm looking for examples with a non-trivial transition kernel, ideally a *class* of Markov chains that converge faster than a geometric rate.

Comment: Consider the Markov Chain where the $(X_n)_n$ are i.i.d.. Then the convergence is instantaneous (which is faster than geometric). You can also construct fastly converging transient Markov Chains with a bit of work.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the construction of transient Markov chains with faster convergence?

Comment: Any course about discrete Markov Chains, for instance "Markov Chains" from J. R. Norris.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything about convergence rates in that book. I've seen other books (like Meyn and Tweedie), where they talk about sub-geometric convergence rates, but nothing about *super*-geometric rates.

Comment: How about random walks on cliques? They converge after one step. In general though, geometric seems right, since after time t, in finite case, you still have at least a geometric probability of never having hit that state.